# How to disable Nokogiri correction

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse HTML files and am using EJS for my server-side templating.

I need to use Nokogiri to parse some EJS files, but the problem is that EJS uses syntax like `<%= order_id %>` as placeholders. This gets removed by Nokogiri which I am guessing is because it treats the file as malformed HTML.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: No, you can't turn it off. Nokogiri is an XML parser first, and then relaxes its rules to parse HTML. You could rewrite the parser rules to add knowledge of markup placeholders I think; The project and source are at https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri. I'd recommend bouncing the idea off the maintainers to get ideas of where to begin, ask why it hasn't been done before, and perhaps write a gem that will modify Nokogiri on the fly rather than hard-coding changes into its source.

Comment: Show a minimal example of the HTML you're trying to parse, and explain what you are trying to do with it. Nokogiri is a great tool for working with real HTML but it's not the only way to process content. You could also pre-process the file, comment out the placeholders, process with Nokogiri, emit the HTML and remove the comment marks to restore the file back to EJS form.

Comment: You will probably need to switch to a non-libxml2-based library for that. Hpricot might do what you want.

Comment: @theTinMan Incidentally that's what I ended up doing. I thought of changing EJS delimiters to {{}}, but apparently that's also not possible in the new versions that always has angular brackets followed by a custom delimiter. So I ended up using [[ ]] as delimiters and converted it into <% %> after Nokogiri completed its job

Comment: @pguardiario I have already written a whole lot of code around Nokogiri, so changing to a different library now is something I wanted to avoid :) Thanks

Comment: Just as a FYI, Nokogiri's API was made to be compatible with Hpricots.